# my sidebar and topbar disappeared after installing nvidia driver

Tags: 12.10, nvidia

I have a `nvidia geforce 520m` graphic card in my laptop and I recently shifted to Ubuntu.
So I tried to install drivers for the graphic card. When I restarted my computer, my topbar and sidebar vanished.
I don't even see close and minimize options for the folders I open.

I can access the terminal and a web browser as their shortcuts are available on the desktop. Can someone please help me out of this situation.

I tried:

- unity-reset
- to delete .so file form the diveres
- X11/ xorg reset

Nothing worked.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 520M] (rev a1)
```

Comment: remove the nvidia drivers

Comment: how? i am new to ubuntu and i dont even know the location of the drivers

Comment: 520m is optimus graphics card (mean dual GPU)? right? if not sure please, drop to console login (alt+ctrl+f1), login and include result of `lspci | grep VGA` in your question.

Comment: @Web-E done! i pasted the results!

Comment: However you were lucky to get the desktop after installing, so no need to boot in recovery mode, you can execute commands from the console login.

Comment: @Web-E can you give me a quick sol please? i've got to get my vm running.. got to submit a project tomorrow!